# Python API run batches of 100,000 in while / for loop without manually changing values

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have about 1.5 million indicators that I have in a csv that I am running through Anomali API.  If I run all through in one go it fails, but if I batch it like:

```
anomali_indicators = anomali_indicators[300000:400000]
```

And do 100000 at a time it completes with no issues, then I can append the files.  But this requires me to go and change the values, and run this 15 times.  Is there a way I can adjust my while and for loop to run 100,000 though at a time and then write to csv, then run the next 100,000 through and so on?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

url = 'https://something.com/api/v2/intelligence/?username='
username = '<username>'
api_key = '<key>'
WAIT_SECONDS = 5

#ANOMALI
anomali_indicators = pd.read_csv('initial_anomali_indicators.csv')
anomali_indicators = anomali_indicators[300000:400000]
anomali_list = anomali_indicators['value'].tolist()
column1 = list()
column2 = list()
column3 = list()
column4 = list()
column5 = list()
i=0
while i < len(anomali_list):
    try:
        for row in anomali_list:
            value_api = url+username+'&api_key='+api_key+'&limit=10000&value='
            responses = requests.get(value_api+row, verify=False)
            data = json.loads(responses.text)
            valuess = data['objects']

            for index in valuess:
                column1.append(index['value'])
                column2.append(index['source'])
                column3.append(index['trusted_circle_ids'])
                column4.append(index['created_ts'])
                column5.append(index['tags'])
        anomali__output = pd.DataFrame({'Indicator': column1,
                                        'Source': column2,
                                        'Trusted Circle': column3,
                                        'Created': column4,
                                        'Tags': column5
                                        })
        i += 1
        break
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        #print(len(column1))
        print("Time to sleep for 5 seconds")
    time.sleep(WAIT_SECONDS)
anomali__output.to_csv('anomali_with_others_first_seen_300000-400000.csv', 
header=True, index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap it with another "batching loop" like this and you're good to go:

```
for batch_idx in range(15):
    current_anomali_indicators = anomali_indicators[batch_idx*100000:(batch_idx+1)*100000]

    # and here goes the rest of your code...
```

Keep in mind that keeping this amount of data in-memory might not be a great idea, thus you may want to write results to your CSV file within a batching loop, per 100k.